# Finding a vector that is orthogonal to n columns of a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

Given a matrix `B` with shape `(M, N)`, where `M > N`. How to find a vector `v` (with shape of `M`) that is perpendicular to all columns in `B`.

I tried using Numpy `numpy.linalg.lstsq` method to solve : `Bx = 0`. `0` here is a vector with `M` zeros.

It returns a vector of zeros with `(N,)` shape.

Comment: I think you are looking for Gram-Schmidt Orthogonization. Maybe [this gist here](https://gist.github.com/iizukak/1287876/edad3c337844fac34f7e56ec09f9cb27d4907cc7) is helpful.

Comment: @NMme Thank you for your reply. The function in the link  you suggested does the same as the numpy function  ‘’’  Q, R = np.linalg.qr(B) ‘’’ ?

Comment: I do not know a lot about linear algebra but the matrix need to be full rank so that equivalence is true according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). However, AFAIK, your matrix is not full rank since you try to find an orthogonal vector and assume is actually exists (which should be the case because of the shape of the matrix)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sympy library, like

```
from sympy import Matrix
B = [[2, 3, 5], [-4, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]]
V = A.nullspace()[0]
```

or to find whole nullspace

```
N = A.nullspace()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me in case someone else need the answer:

```
u,s,vh=np.linalg.svd(B)
v=vh[-1:1]
```